# CARTO polygon styles

Tags: carto

How do I assign polygon colors in CARTO based on whether it is a positive or negative number? For example, I want the range of negatives to be one color, and the range of positives another, with a gradient in each.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making your map in [Builder](https://carto.com/builder/)? If so you can use [Style By Value](https://carto.com/help/building-maps/style-by-value/) with one of the default [diverging](https://carto.com/carto-colors/) color schemes.

If that's not what you need you can make your own bin breaks instead. To do that set Builder's STYLE panel toggle to CartoCSS and write your own [conditional CartoCSS code](https://carto.com/help/building-maps/basic-cartocss-for-map-styling/#cartocss-conditional-styling) or write your own [TurboCARTO code](https://carto.com/help/building-maps/style-thematic-maps-with-turbocarto/) there.

Comment: The diverging color scheme doesn't allow me to set zero as the defining separator. Sadly, I cannot figure out how to write code that sets zero as the defining middle of the colors, either. I've never written CSS, so I need more guidance than the references have. Ugh. Sorry. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: Example in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848253/how-do-i-dynamically-create-cartocss-for-a-choropleth-with-cartodb. The conditions are in brackets. Each bracket & it's code block = one choropleth bin, plus technically the 1st code block is a bin also. You can create conditions using operators, ie >0. Bottom conditions override top ones.